# поиск в Li элементах используя regexp

Tags: javascript

я пытаюсь найти li элемент который содержит "javascript" и сделать с ним чтолибо но ничего не работает, буду рад если поможите.
html

```
<span id="search">button</span>
        <ul id="result">
            <li>php</li>
            <li>javascript 1</li>
            <li>ruby</li>
            <li>javascript 2</li>
            <li>java</li>
        </ul>
```

js

```
function ready() {
    document.getElementById("search").onclick = function dosearch() {
        var x = document.getElementById("result");
        var items = x.getElementsByTagName("li");
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (/javascript/i.test(items[i].innerHtml)) {
                items[i].style.color = "red";
            }
        }
    }; 
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

Comment: вам бы текст в `li` а не сам элемент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы проверяете регуляркой не строчку, а DOM ноду.
В результате получается `/javascript/i.test(страннаяФигняАНеСтрочкаСТекстом);`
Содержимое из dom ноды можно получить в данном случае [**с помощью innerHTML**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).
Например так:

```
/javascript/i.test(items[i].innerHTML);
```

Ну и да, у вас опечатки в html:
javasc**t**ipt вместо javascript

Comment: вот так if (/javascript/i.test(items[i].innerHtml)) ?

Comment: @DimaVleskov ну да, остальная логика остается той же

Comment: я исправил эти ошибки но после нажатия li элемент color = "red" не применяеться, подскажите как исправить это, вроде уже как всё на месте

Comment: А почему никто `//.exec()` не использует? Как по мне удобнее... :)

Comment: @DimaVleskov не исправил. Регистр - важен. innerHTML а не innerHtml

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь работает

Comment: @DimaVleskov, отметь ответ, как правильный

Comment: @Yuri потому что если я тут пытаюсь точечно помочь с минимальными изменениями, а то у топикстартера мозг выкипит. Ну и мне лень расписывать офк =)

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector("#search").addEventListener('click', e => {
  let allowed = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#result > li')).filter(i => /javascript/i.test(i.innerHTML));
  console.info(allowed);
});
```

```html
<span id="search">button</span>
        <ul id="result">
            <li>php</li>
            <li>javascript 1</li>
            <li>ruby</li>
            <li>javasctipt 2</li>
            <li>java</li>
        </ul>
```